# Is there a way to make a CSS3 animation stop and then start again after 5 seconds?

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to create a CSS3 animation that will start when the page has been loaded. I am looking the animation to stop and not repeat straight away. I would like like the animation to then begin again in 5 seconds. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Here is the code I have so far that just keeps repeating the animation. I would like the animation to repeat after it is first loaded in another 5 seconds.

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'BebasRegular', sans-serif;
    font-size: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    background: #E9AB17 -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#e8a917), to(#f4b011), color-stop(0.5, #fff)) 0 0 no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: 155px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-animation-name: shine;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;    
}
@-webkit-keyframes shine {
    0% {
        background-position: top left;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: top right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I just removed your "Thanks in advance" because it's usual practice here not to include it. Welcome !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about making the animation duration 7s:

```
-webkit-animation-name: shine;
-webkit-animation-duration: 7s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

and adding a keyframe at around 2s, being the same that the final one:

```
@-webkit-keyframes shine {
    0%  {
        background-position: top left;
    }
    28%, 100% {
        background-position: top right;
    }
}
```

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/ScEme/)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, that has worked fine. Appreciate it.